# AWS Elastic Beanstalk: HTTP Header not appearing in Flask application

Tags: flask, http-headers

I have a small Flask application that I want to run on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

The application deploys and runs fine but I've noticed that a custom HTTP Header (HTTP_CUSTOM_TOKEN) is not present in `request.headers`.

I'm assuming I'm missing something from the Apache configuration but am not very familiar with that environment.

Answer (score 10):

What you need is something similar to what @Fartash suggested, just slightly different.

Add `.ebextensions/python.config` :

```
container_commands:
  03wsgipass:
    command: 'echo "WSGIPassAuthorization On" >> ../wsgi.conf'
```

as explained at [Using the AWS Elastic Beanstalk Python Platform](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-container.html)

Comment: Hey, what does "../wsgi.conf" refer to? an existing file?

Comment: The "../wsgi.conf"  file will be created if it doesn't exist. See https://askubuntu.com/a/401926

Comment: ../wsgi.conf must refer to a path that is somehow read by Apache HTTPD.
Is this documented somewhere?

Answer (score 5):

Remove underscores from the header variables,
example:-

`header_var_val = "some value"`
replace it with -- `headervarval = "some value"`

Answer (score 4):

You need to enable the WSGIPassAuthorization. If you do not specifically enable auth forwarding, apache will consume the required headers and your app won't receive it.

Add this to your *.config file in .ebextensions folder.

`commands:
  WSGIPassAuthorization:
    command: sed -i.bak '/WSGIScriptAlias/ a WSGIPassAuthorization On' config.py
    cwd: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks`

Comment: what does config.py refer to?